# how to write a right aggregation class in swift

Tags: swift, class, aggregation

for example, I have a class about Vehicle, in this class, I have a private property with the name of date, this property should get one or more data related to time from another class that with the named of CalendarInfo. The CalendarInfo class has an aggregation relation to the Vehicle class. Since I am completely new in swift, I just need help to understand the concept of the code that I needed to write for this, to link a property from a class to another class that has an aggregation relation. I hope you can understand what I mean.

[image: Here is a schematic version of the UML diagram for the system that I explained to you about]

here is the code I am not sure that they are right

```
class Vehicle {

private var id: UInt?
private var model = ""
private var dateTimes = CalendarInfo() //I have problem in this line
}

class CalenderInfo {
private var id: UInt?
private var Date = Calendar
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The direction is right, but you have some typos and compilation issues.
Here is the compilable version:

```
import Foundation

class Vehicle {

    private var id: UInt?
    private var model = ""
    private var dateTimes: CalendarInfo = CalendarInfo()
}

class CalendarInfo {
    private var id: UInt?
    private var date: Calendar

    init() {
        id = 0
        date = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for an initializer for such a simple class, both `id` and `date` can be assigned a value outside the initializer. There's also no need for the type annotation of `dateTimes`.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kirakosyan I can't thank you enough, the concept of this process was unclear to me. Your post is so helpful

Answer (score -1):

If you need an aggregate relationship between the `CalendarInfo` and `Vehicle` and if I understand it correctly from the diagram and what you've written you would want a one to many relationship between the `Vehicle` object and the `CalendarInfo`.

To achieve that you would want a collection type for your `CalendarInfo` in the `Vehicle` definition, you can achieve that by doing something like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Vehicle {
  var id: UInt?
  var model: String
  var dateTimes: [CalendarInfo] //I have problem in this line
}

struct CalendarInfo {
  var id: UInt?
  var date: Date
}


let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let myCalendar = [CalendarInfo(id: 1, date: dateFormatter.date(from:"2019-02-10")!),
                  CalendarInfo(id: 2, date: dateFormatter.date(from:"2019-02-15")!),
                  CalendarInfo(id: 3, date: dateFormatter.date(from:"2019-02-20")!)]

let myCar = Vehicle(id: 1, model: "Honda", dateTimes: myCalendar)

myCar.dateTimes.count == 3 //true
```